# Mixed effects model output - no difference in AIC values

Tags: r, mixed-model, predictive-models, model-selection, aic

In our study we are looking at the change in the numbers of acoustically tagged fish detections with respect to tidal state (ebbing, flowing), light period (dawn, day, dusk, night) and month (February, March, April, May, June). Detection data is in the form of counts per light stage and corresponding tidal stage and month. Detections are transformed through log transformation and tide, light and month are all set as factors.

I've followed the protocol by Zuur et al (2009) and am therefore using mixed effects models to account for the repeated measures by each unique fish (fish.id is the random effect).

My issue arises at the model selection stage where anova of the models with sequential fixed effects left out:

```
lmer.1  <- lmer(logdetections ~  tide + light + month + tide:light + (1|fish.id), 
                data=Sea_Bass_Data_2log, REML=FALSE)
lmer.2  <- lmer(logdetections ~ light + month + tide:light + (1|fish.id), 
                data=Sea_Bass_Data_2log, REML=FALSE)
lmer.3  <- lmer(logdetections ~  tide + month + tide:light + (1|fish.id), 
                data=Sea_Bass_Data_2log, REML=FALSE)
lmer.4  <- lmer(logdetections ~  tide + light + tide:light + (1|fish.id), 
                data=Sea_Bass_Data_2log, REML=FALSE)
lmer.5  <- lmer(logdetections ~ tide + light + month + (1|fish.id), 
                data=Sea_Bass_Data_2log, REML=FALSE)
lmer.6  <- lmer(logdetections ~ 1 + (1|fish.id), 
                data=Sea_Bass_Data_2log, REML=FALSE)
```

An anova of the above models finds that 3 models have the same AIC value and weights.

```
> anova(lmer.1, lmer.2, lmer.3, lmer.4, lmer.5, lmer.6)
Data: Sea_Bass_Data_2log
Models:
lmer.6: logdetections ~ 1 + (1 | fish.id)
lmer.4: logdetections ~ tide + light + tide:light + (1 | fish.id)
lmer.5: logdetections ~ tide + light + month + (1 | fish.id)
lmer.1: logdetections ~ tide + light + month + tide:light + (1 | fish.id)
lmer.2: logdetections ~ light + month + tide:light + (1 | fish.id)
lmer.3: logdetections ~ tide + month + tide:light + (1 | fish.id)
       Df    AIC    BIC  logLik deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)    
lmer.6  3 450.23 461.86 -222.12   444.23                             
lmer.4 10 390.65 429.43 -185.32   370.65 73.583      7  2.781e-13 ***
lmer.5 11 382.41 425.06 -180.20   360.41 10.242      1   0.001373 ** 
lmer.1 14 378.02 432.31 -175.01   350.02 10.383      3   0.015579 *  
lmer.2 14 378.02 432.31 -175.01   350.02  0.000      0  < 2.2e-16 ***
lmer.3 14 378.02 432.31 -175.01   350.02  0.000      0   1.000000    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I've used the "bbmle" package to look at AICc and weights and find the same result:

```
> bbmle::AICctab(lmer.1, lmer.2, lmer.3, lmer.4, lmer.5, lmer.6, base = T,     weights = T)
       AICc  dAICc df weight
lmer.2 379.3   0.0 14 0.318 
lmer.3 379.3   0.0 14 0.318 
lmer.1 379.3   0.0 14 0.318 
lmer.5 383.2   3.9 11 0.045 
lmer.4 391.3  12.0 10 <0.001
lmer.6 450.3  71.0 3  <0.001
```

I then used the "MuMIn" package function model.avg but am no closer to understanding its output for model selection.

```
> model.avg(lmer.1, lmer.2, lmer.3)

Call:
model.avg(object = lmer.1, lmer.2, lmer.3)

Component models: 
‘124’  ‘234’  ‘1234’

Coefficients: 
       (Intercept)  lightday  lightdusk lightnight    month3    month4       month5
full     0.2603615 0.4141133 0.09135152  0.2023542 0.1938293 0.5564969    0.4062781
subset   0.2603615 0.6211699 0.13702728  0.3035313 0.1938293 0.5564969 0.4062781
      month6 lightdawn:tideFlooding lightday:tideFlooding  lightdusk:tideFlooding
full   0.3912216            0.002832931            -0.1251204            -0.09993087
subset 0.3912216            0.008498793            -0.1251204            -0.09993087
       lightnight:tideFlooding tideFlooding lightday:tideEbbing lightday:tideFlooding
full                0.03964991  0.005665860           0.2070566               -0.1251204
subset              0.03964991  0.008498789           0.6211699            -0.1251204
       lightdusk:tideEbbing lightdusk:tideFlooding lightnight:tideEbbing
full             0.04567576            -0.09993087             0.1011771
subset           0.13702728            -0.09993087             0.3035313
       lightnight:tideFlooding
full                0.03964991
subset              0.03964991
```

Can anyone advise on how I should select the correct model?

Comment: All three of those models are equivalent (so it doesn't matter which one you pick). The basic problem is that if you include the interaction between categorical variables (`tide:light`), even without the main effects of `tide` and `light`, you will always implicitly get them.  For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696044/lmem-chi-square-0-prob-1-whats-wrong-with-my-code/40696250#40696250

Comment: Just looking at some of the answers below, to fir the model better and to get a better understanding of the influence of the fixed effects, would it be better to drop the interaction term completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three models you've constructed differ in the ways the parameters are defined, but they have the same number of the parameters and the fits are equivalent in every way except for the numerical values of the parameters.

We can illustrate this with a plain linear model - mixed models just complicate the issue.

```
set.seed(101)
dd <- expand.grid(light=c("day","dusk","night"),
                  tide=c("base","Flooding","Ebbing"))
dd$y <- rnorm(nrow(dd))
## add one more row so fit isn't perfect
dd <- rbind(dd,dd[1,])
dd$y[nrow(dd)] <- rnorm(1)
```

Use `model.matrix` to see what parameters R will construct when fitting the model (you could also use `names(coef(...))` on the output of `lm()`, or `names(fixef(...))` on the output of `(g)lmer`).

```
tmpf <- function(f) {
    model.matrix(f,data=dd)
}
colnames(m1 <- tmpf(~light+tide+light:tide))
## [1] "(Intercept)"             "lightdusk"              
## [3] "lightnight"              "tideFlooding"           
## [5] "tideEbbing"              "lightdusk:tideFlooding" 
## [7] "lightnight:tideFlooding" "lightdusk:tideEbbing"   
## [9] "lightnight:tideEbbing"
```

If we use the `*` operator, we get the interaction plus the main effects; if we redundantly specify the main effects, R silently drops them.

```
all.equal(m1,tmpf(~light*tide))  ## TRUE
all.equal(m1,tmpf(~light+light*tide))  ## TRUE
all.equal(m1,tmpf(~light+tide+light*tide))  ## TRUE
```

If we use `:` but leave out one of the main effects we get the *same number of parameters* (9), but they are organized differently:

```
colnames(m2 <- tmpf(~light+light:tide))
## [1] "(Intercept)"             "lightdusk"              
## [3] "lightnight"              "lightday:tideFlooding"  
## [5] "lightdusk:tideFlooding"  "lightnight:tideFlooding"
## [7] "lightday:tideEbbing"     "lightdusk:tideEbbing"   
## [9] "lightnight:tideEbbing"
```

As I explain [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40696044/lmem-chi-square-0-prob-1-whats-wrong-with-my-code/40696250#40696250), it rarely makes sense to test the model with interactions present but main effects missing; the only ways that I know of to do this are to construct the dummy variables yourself (either by hand, or by constructing the model matrix, dropping the terms you don't want, and using the remaining model matrix columns as (numeric) predictor variables.

The `MuMIn` package tries to do the right thing: from `?dredge`,

> By default, marginality constraints are respected, so “all possible combinations” include only those containing interactions with their respective main effects and all lower order terms.

```
library(MuMIn)    
full_model <- lm(y~light*tide,data=dd,na.action="na.fail")    
(dmods <- dredge(full_model))
## Model selection table 
##      (Int) lgh tid lgh:tid df logLik   AICc  delta weight
## 8 -0.27460   +   +       + 10 23.541 -247.1   0.00      1
## 1  0.24500                  2 -8.291   22.3 269.38      0
## 3 -0.16790       +          4 -5.948   27.9 274.98      0
## 2  0.07096   +              4 -7.821   31.6 278.72      0
## 4 -0.25820   +   +          6 -5.543   51.1 298.17      0
```

As you can see `dredge` has not tried to fit any models with the interaction but missing some main effects.

Answer (score 0):

The order of effects in a linear model do not change the fitted values and consequently, the inference and AIC. Interestingly, the tide coefficient disappears from model 2. As a reminder the formula object in R creates a product term alone when you use the `:` operator, but adjusts for product and lower levels when you use `*` operator. The latter is considered the more statistically cogent approach, as the product term is almost never interpretable without the lower level terms. `lmer.2` is the only object not to have tide as a first order fixed effect.

The only reason *this* might be the case has to do with possible singularity in these data. With all the covariates having a factor level, it's possible that one or more covariates in the "full" model, e.g. the model containing first order effects for tide, month, and light as well as the interaction between tide and light, is aliased. If you pass the fixed effects command, e.g. `fixef` from `lmer.1` you would expect to see at least one `NA` term because R uses a pseudoinverse.

Comment: I think @BenBolker has already suggested that this is not in fact the case. See the answer to which he links in his comment above.

Comment: @mdewey the models are *not* equivalent except for overspecification. Compare `terms(~ light + month + tide:light)` to `terms(~  tide + light + month + tide:light)`. Had the OP used the `*` operator instead of the `:`, these would be equivalent.

Comment: the `terms` attributes are not identical, but the model matrices generated from these formulas will have the same number of parameters and will give rise to identical predictions and goodness-of-fit statistics. (Look in particular at the `factors` attribute, and the fact that `light:tide` is coded as 1 in one case and 2 in the other ... see `?terms.object`.)

Comment: @BenBolker Please try the following example and explain if I have misunderstood, `Dat <- expand.grid(tide= 0:1, light=0:1, month=0:1)`. `D1 <- model.matrix( ~  tide + light + month + tide:light, data=Dat)`. `D2 <- model.matrix(~ light + month + tide:light, data=Dat)`. `ncol(D1) == ncol(D2)`.

Comment: Good example, but: make the variables into factors (as is the case in the OP's example -- you can tell this by looking at the parameter names in the model-averaged output) (in fact, I just noticed that they also say it explicitly in their question ... "and tide, light and month are all set as factors") and try it again ...

Comment: @BenBolker Binary is a special case of factors. Can you create an example which *doesn't* involve singularity of terms?

Comment: R treats numeric and factor variables differently, so a binary variable coded as numeric or factor will lead to different models/outcomes. Can you be a little more specific about what you mean by "singularity of terms" (sorry if I'm being stupid about it)?

Comment: To remove the issue of the inclusion of both light and tide on the model, is it better to remove their interaction (tide:light) from the model entirely?

Comment: Only remove the interaction if that is what, in the light of your underlying scientific question, you really want to do.

Comment: Good point. Would I therefore have an issue reporting the original model (were the best fitted model used to include the "tide:light" interaction) given the points made by Ben?